Printing figures with thin hulls / double outer layers
In Blender etc. many 3D models are composed of objects with double hulls. For instance, an arm might not just a hollow cylinder with a single outer surface but is often "moulded" out of a torus and thus has 2 surface layers like any real world object would have.
If one wants to print such a figure the space between these outer layers can be filled by the slicer software but of course the rest of the space within the arm cylinder remains hollow. This can lead to very thin und unstable walls.
I don't see a way to fix this aside from redrawing such figures.
But maybe one of you has found an ingenious way of fixing this.

Would making the model solid work for you?

Blender is notorious for creating objects that do not print well. This is because of incorrect use of Blender. Please use the search at the top of the page to find similar questions, this might help you solve the issue or give insight to update the question.

If the inner and outer shell are two separate grids, just deleting the inner one will solve the problem. If they are one contiguous grid (with a hole), split it into two at the hole, delete the inner part, and seal the hole.
